# Noise Equivalent Bandwith of IIR and FIR Filters?

Tags: noise, infinite-impulse-response, bandwidth, finite-impulse-response

How do you calculate the noise equivalent bandwidth for an IIR or FIR filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, isn't it the same as for any filter?

$$
B_\text{eq} = \frac{1}{|H(e^{j\omega_0})|^2} \int_0^\infty |H(e^{j\omega})|^2 d\omega
$$

where $H(e^{j\omega})$ is the frequency response, and $\omega_0$ is the max-abs frequency. For FIR filters, you can just use e.g. `freqz` in MATLAB/Octave. For IIR filters, you'd have to do analysis or take measurements (or see if you can get away with truncating)

Comment: Shouldn't the denominator term be $|H(e^{j\omega_0})|^2$ ? http://www.onmyphd.com/?p=enbw.equivalent.noise.bandwidth

Comment: Yes you are correct, I'll fix it

Comment: Shouldn't it be in discrete frequency, not continuous?

Comment: I do not think so. The DTFT is continuous (actually a complex Fourier series).